# Ability to have a method callback from an annotation?

Tags: java

I am trying to have an annotation `@FeatureDependent` be used on methods to signal that the method requires certain things to be enabled in order for it to work. And I was wondering if it was possible to have a method called everytime a method with `@FeatureDependent` was called which would check if the criteria were met for the method to be called.

Comment: Can anybody call these methods or is it centralized? What do you want to do if the check fails? A lots of things are possible with Annotations, but we don't have enough information to help you there.

Comment: Sorry, anybody can call these methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [Aspect Oriented Programming (AOI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).  This technique allows you to address "cross-cutting" concerns, tasks like logging, security, and transaction management which tend to affect many methods in the same manner.  Your use case sounds like it would be a good fit for AOP.

There are two common approaches to AOP.  The first mechanism is to create objects in a container (e.g. a Spring container).  The container can then scan the class, detect any advice that needs to be applied, and apply the advice via dynamic proxies (Googling Spring and AOP is a good place to start with this).  The downside is that your components will need to be constructed by a container so it makes sense for larger components.

The second approach is an extra compilation step (sometimes done at compilation, sometimes done as a separate compilation phase, and sometimes done by a weaving class loader) to wire in the additional methods.  This is typically called "weaving" and AspectJ is a common library to look into for this.

Both approaches will allow you to apply "advice" (code run before and after a method invocation) based on annotations on an object.  Explaining either in more detail would be beyond the scope of a SO answer but I hope it can get you started.

I should warn that AOP has gotten a bit of a reputation for complicating the flow of an application and tending to be difficult to understand and debug.  As a result it has declined in popularity lately.

Another approach is to use something like [Servlet Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html), basically a single choke point for all requests and workflows where you can apply various logging & security mechanisms.  Such an approach tends to be a little easier to understand and involve a bit less "black magic".